# Android: How to handle Customview on savedInstancestate and resotreInstancestate

Tags: android

How to handle Customview on savedInstancestate and resotreInstancestate?. Customview contains streaming video. Once i go to next activity and come to previous activity the streaming video is not visible. How to handle this?

```
MjpegView container = (MjpegView)findViewById(R.id.video1_surface);
container.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(Url)); 

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: MjpegView extends SurfaceView

Answer (score 0):

You may got confusing when consider CustomView in your case. And I don't know what you want to sustain within activities: the video data or link to it?

Base on your description, I guess that you want to maintain a data while switching back and ford with 2 activities. To do so, you should use `SharedPreferences`:

```
public void AppSaveData(Context context, String data_key, String what_to_save)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = Context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_STORE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);          
        prefs.edit().putString(data_key, what_to_save).commit();
    }

public String AppGetData(Context context, String data_key)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_STORE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);          
        return prefs.getString(data_key,"http://default_link.html");
    }
```

Note: context is your `main activity` or `yourActivity.getApplicationContext()`